Detect clicks on every part of the screen, one widget at a time
I have a series of buttons, all built from the same parent widget.
The click on a button turns on listening.
The isListening bool is a global variable, because listening is handled by a provider.
To turn off listening, I want to be able to click not only on the same button, but also on any other part of the screen.
I had tried to wrap the buttons with a TapRegion, as in the code below, but this applies to each button, so I lost information on which button was turned on.
I would like to activate the TapRegion only when the corresponding button is clicked, and then deactivate it, does anyone know how to do it or have better solutions?
Thanks in advance!
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TapRegion(
    key: ValueKey((key as ValueKey<dynamic>).value),
    onTapOutside: (tap) => isListening ? stopListening() : null,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: isListening ? stopListening : startListening,
        child: Icon(isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_off),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


Try using the render box to get the positions of the buttons and compare them with the positions when tapped to detect which button is being clicked.
